# Multiclass classification, IndexError: Target 2 is out of bounds

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, multiclass-classification

I am facing a multiclass classification problem related to the activity of some drugs using Pytorch neural net, I have three activity classes (0, 1 and 2), to tackle the problem I adopted the one vs. one approach, thus creating three binary classifiers: 0 vs. 1, 1 vs. 2 and 2 vs. 0. When I train the second classifier (class 1 vs. class 2) I get the following error:

```
IndexError: Target 2 is out of bounds.
```

Is there a method to solve it without reassigning labels? Thank you all!

This is my net, is a Graph Isomorphism Network build with Pytorch Geometric:

```
class GIN1(torch.nn.Module): 
  def __init__(self, h):
     super(GIN1, self).__init__()
     dim_h_conv = h
     dim_h_fc = dim_h_conv*5

     # Convolutional layers
     self.conv1 = GINConv(Sequential(Linear(14, dim_h_conv),
                                     BatchNorm1d(dim_h_conv), ReLU(),
                                     Linear(dim_h_conv, dim_h_conv), ReLU()))
     self.conv2 = GINConv(Sequential(Linear(dim_h_conv, dim_h_conv),
                                     BatchNorm1d(dim_h_conv), ReLU(),
                                     Linear(dim_h_conv, dim_h_conv), ReLU()))
     self.conv3 = GINConv(Sequential(Linear(dim_h_conv, dim_h_conv),
                                     BatchNorm1d(dim_h_conv), ReLU(),
                                     Linear(dim_h_conv, dim_h_conv), ReLU()))
     self.conv4 = GINConv(Sequential(Linear(dim_h_conv, dim_h_conv),
                                     BatchNorm1d(dim_h_conv), ReLU(),
                                     Linear(dim_h_conv, dim_h_conv), ReLU()))
     self.conv5 = GINConv(Sequential(Linear(dim_h_conv, dim_h_conv),
                                     BatchNorm1d(dim_h_conv), ReLU(),
                                     Linear(dim_h_conv, dim_h_conv), ReLU()))
 
     # Fully connected layers
     self.lin1 = Linear(dim_h_fc, dim_h_fc)
     self.lin2 = Linear(dim_h_fc, 2)

     self.initialize_w()

  def forward(self, x, edge_index, batch):
    h1 = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
    h2 = self.conv2(h1, edge_index)
    h3 = self.conv3(h2, edge_index)
    h4 = self.conv4(h3, edge_index)
    h5 = self.conv5(h4, edge_index)

    # Graph level readout
    h1 = global_add_pool(h1, batch)
    h2 = global_add_pool(h2, batch)
    h3 = global_add_pool(h3, batch)
    h4 = global_add_pool(h4, batch)
    h5 = global_add_pool(h5, batch)

    # Concatenate graph embeddings
    h = torch.cat((h1, h2, h3, h4, h5), dim=1)

    # Classifier
    h = self.lin1(h)
    h = h.relu()
    h = F.dropout(h, p=hp_gin1['p'], training=self.training)
    h = self.lin2(h)
    h = F.log_softmax(h, dim=1)

    return h

  def initialize_w(self):
    for m in self.modules():

      if isinstance(m, Linear):
        torch.nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight, mode='fan_in', nonlinearity='relu')
        torch.nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)

      if isinstance(m, BatchNorm1d):
        torch.nn.init.constant_(m.weight, 1)
        torch.nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
```

And this is my training loop:

```
gin2 = GIN2(h=hp_gin2['h']) #40
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(gin2.parameters(), lr=hp_gin2['lr']) 
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

def train(train_loader):
  gin2.train()
  loss_all = 0
  for data in train_loader:
    output = gin2(data.x, data.edge_index, data.batch)
    loss = criterion(output, data.y)

    l2_lambda = hp_gin2['lambda']
    l2_norm = sum(p.pow(2.0).sum()
                 for p in gin2.parameters())
    loss = loss + l2_lambda * l2_norm

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    loss_all += loss.item() * data.num_graphs
  return loss_all / len(train_loader.dataset)

def test_loss(loader):
  total_loss_val = 0
  with torch.no_grad():
   for data in loader:
     output = gin2(data.x, data.edge_index, data.batch)
     batch_loss = criterion(output, data.y)
  
     total_loss_val += batch_loss.item() * data.num_graphs
  return total_loss_val / len(loader.dataset)

def test(loader):
  gin2.eval()
  correct = 0
  for data in loader:
    output = gin2(data.x, data.edge_index, data.batch)

    accuracy = Accuracy(average='macro', num_classes=2)
    acc = accuracy(output, data.y)

  return acc
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you might be trying to use an index of 2 on an output of length 1? Could we get more code? It's pretty much impossible to solve this problem without seeing the line causing the error.

Comment: @DWKOT Sorry for the forgetfulness, I added my neural network to the post. Basically I have a subdataset with data labeled as 1 or 2, and I should perform a classification between these two classes. And I get the same error if I try to run class 2 vs. class 0 classification

Comment: Where's your main function where you create the GIN1 class and use it? And do you have  a longer stack trace to determine which line is causing the error?

Comment: @DWKOT I also added the functions I use to train my network and the screenshot of the error taken from colab

Comment: So to make sure I'm understanding, your labels (in `data.y`) are '0', '1', or '2', but your model only outputs a vector with 2 values (i.e. `self.lin2 = Linear(dim_h_fc, 2)` is the last layer of your model, and specifies the shape of the output). It seems to me like your loss function is saying 'OK, the true label is 2, what's the probability associated with that label?' and getting an indexing error when it tries to access that index which doesn't exist. What if the last layer of your model returned logits for all 3 classes, that is it would look like `self.lin2 = Linear(dim_h_fc, 3)`

Comment: @DWKOT yes, you understand. If I perform multiclass classification on the full dataset, where there are data with the three labels, there is no problem if I use **self.lin2 = Linear(dim_h_fc, 3)**. But using the one vs. one method I now have to perform the classification on the binary sub dataset containing data with labels 1 and 2

Comment: Ahh I see, so PyTorch uses the labels you provide as indices to the output vector in calculating loss. So your options would be to change the labels to be 0-indexed (which is what your question is trying to avoid), have a multiclass model (which you're also trying to avoid), or like, tell PyTorch "don't just use the plain labels for loss calculation, use a custom mapping between labels and 0/1 instead".  Maybe you could make a custom loss function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248580/discussion-between-gianmarco-luchetti-and-dwkot).

Comment: @DWKOT Or I could directly set three classes with **self.lin2 = Linear(dim_h_fc, 3)**. E.g. if I go to perform the 1 vs. 2 classification I should not have samples that are classified into 0, since the network does not have samples belonging to that class. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think that would work, if you think it would fit your use case.

Comment: @DWKOT I tried it and it works, taking the example of the 1 vs. 2 classification from the confusion matrix I observed that indeed no sample is classified as 0, same thing for the 2 vs. 0 case. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome! I'll summarize this discussion in an answer and you can mark this as done.

Answer (score 2):

OP needed to match the output dimension of their model with the number of label classes (see discussion).